# Lucene as backing storage for memcached

Tags: architecture, lucene, memcached, readonly

Did anyone try using lucene as a backing storage for memcached?

Here's  the deal:
Im working on the architecture for scalable static data storage. The firm decided to make localization of certain static info, so soon we will have 20 translations of our DB entities, this will give approximately +4G overall static text. The nature of the data is completely readonly (it's primarly geolocations, and user summaries translations).

So I decided to go with lucene, because of its NIOFSDirectory and MMapDirectory. The problem is that we're running 32bit jvm => so soon cool times with MMapDirectory will finish (so far I did architecture for 2 languages). I tested NIOFSDirectory and its performance looks appealing, but I don't realy like high disk usage, so I'm thinking about memcached and usign NIOFSDirectory as a backup storage when something happen to memcached process.

Physcally it will be like every node in the app. cluster will contain those 4G text in the memcached process and backed by lucene' NIOFSDirectory.

So what you folks think? Is this arch. good one?

Answer (score 2):

Lucene is known for its search capabilities: it is able to run complex queries against rapidly changing corpora of unstructured documents thanks to its inverted index and use of neat algorithms.

However, it doesn't do anything revolutionary regarding I/O operations, so it looks strange to me to use such a complex and powerful piece of software for doing mainly primary-key lookups. I am expecting some simpler softwares dedicated to key-value storage to perform much better than Lucene at this task.